# AH3766Q doubt about working principle

Tags: sensor, proximity-sensor

The AH3766Q is a Bipolar Latch Operation (South Pole: On, North Pole: off). Flipping the sensor makes it trigger in the opposite way (South Pole: Off, North Pole: on)?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> The AH3766Q is a Bipolar Latch Operation (South Pole: On, North Pole: off). Flipping the sensor makes it trigger in the opposite way (South Pole: Off, North Pole: on)?

Yes. Sort-of.

This device latches, and exhibits [hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis). Which is good for electrically noisy environments.

Looking at the first image, `Brp`, `0`, and `Bop` are the magnetic field direction.  Reverse, none, and forward.

At zero flux, the device is "off" so it's open-drain MOSFET output will be floating, and is pulled up to Vdd through RL in the [datasheet example circuit](https://octopart.com/datasheet/ah3766q-p-b-diodes+inc.-61256183). So output is logical high.  This is the top part (Vdd) of the hysteresis image.

As flux is increased in forward direction (as shown in above image), nothing happens until flux reaches level `Bop` at top-right.  When this flux level is reached, this device switches on, pulling it's MOSFET drain to near zero Volts. So output is then a logical low. Now we are at the bottom-right (on state) of the hysteresis image.

As flux returns to zero, nothing changes - output is still low.

As flux reverses and increases, nothing changes - output is still low.  Until the reverse flux reaches level `Brp` at bottom-left, at which point the device turns off, allowing the output to go high (top-left.)